# Sum row in VBA excel doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and coding in general.
I was trying my best to create a little VBA to help me automatically sum the rows of a table. 
In my code, I have bolded the output. ie. after i click the macro, the sum is supposed to show and it is also supposed to be bolded.

However,I am not sure where I went wrong. :o Whenever I run, there is nothing seen.
I have tried to solve it by myself but it finds fault with the

```
.Cells(j, 1stCol + 1)
```

for both lines. I am not sure if there are any other faults because I cannot troubleshoot this myself.

Could anybody kindly help?
Also, does anybody have any good books to read up more on VBA? The internet confuses me quite a lot of the time I am trying to learn.

Thank you all for your help!

here is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub addHorizontalSums()

Dim lstCol As Integer
With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


lstCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column

Dim j As Integer
For j = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(j, 1stCol + 1) = "=SUM(RC[-" & lstCol - 1 & "]:RC[-1])"
    .Cells(j, 1stCol + 1).Font.Bold = True


Next j


End With

End Sub
```

---

This is an update...
Davesexcel,

1. The formula you gave I think only works if all the rows are the same length, however, if they arent, it will cut the data in half based on the first row found. I need to be able to calculate rows of different lengths.
2. The updated code you gave doesnt work too well. If you look at the Note Column, there are like many gaps of different gap spaces and the latest formula always results in debug message, without being fully calculated.
3. Is there a way for me to SUM all the numbers in each little sub-table BUT only subtracting the last no. Eg. if there are 9 items in a list with the 10th being the subtotal, is there code to SUM the 9 and then subtract the 10th, to give an overall result of 0?
4. Lastly, is it possible to highlight all the data that is being churned out, say in yellow? This would help me do the recording down quickly.

Thanks guys for all of your help!

Appreciated with much thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: Your variable is **L**STCOL and not 1STCOL, which is not a legal variable name.

Comment: I'd think the `Option Explicit` would catch that, but perhaps not. Try typing out the name to make the first letter less ambiguous, `Dim firstCol as Integer` then just use `firstCol` instead of `1/l`.

Comment: @BruceWayne `Option Explicit` won't catch an invalidly named variable - it just gets flagged as a syntax error.

Comment: @BruceWayne - to expand on Rory's comment, if it was `LSTCO1` then **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** would catch it as a missing variable. However, you cannot start a variable name with a number so the primary error for `1STCOL` is **Syntax Error**. It's wrong twice; the one that gets reported is syntax error.

Comment: @Jeeped - Ahh, I see what y'all mean now. Good call, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably meant to write lstCol instead of 1stCol in the For-loop.

Second, if I get you right you want to show the sum of each row after the last cell in each row. If so, the variable j must go from 1 to the number of rows used on your sheet, not the number of columns. The following code should do the task.

```
Sub addHorizontalSums()

Dim j As Integer
Dim lstCol As Integer

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lstCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column

        For j = 1 To .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            .Cells(j, lstCol + 1) = "=SUM(RC[-" & lstCol - 1 & "]:RC[-1])"
            .Cells(j, lstCol + 1).Font.Bold = True

        Next j

End With

End Sub
```

As a remark, you might want to use a different way to determine lstCol in case you have different numbers of entries in each row. You could for example use the following code, which I think should be more robust:

```
Sub addHorizontalSums()

Dim j As Integer

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For j = 1 To .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

            .Rows(j).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rows(j))
            .Rows(j).End(xlToRight).Font.Bold = True

    Next j

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the number of rows to equal the number of columns, you should count the columns and rows separately.

For example,(change 1 to 2 in the `rng`,if you want it to start on row 2)

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim LstCol As Long, LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, Sh As Worksheet

    Set Sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Sh
        LstCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LstCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, LstCol + 1), .Cells(LstRw, LstCol + 1))
    End With

    With Rng
        .Formula = "=SUM(RC[-" & LstCol & "]:RC[-1])"
        .Font.Bold = 1
        .Value = .Value 'use if you only want to show values, not formula
    End With

End Sub
```

### Sum between blanks

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

### [image: After]

```
Sub SumBetweenBlanks()
    Dim RangeArea As Range, x As Long

    x = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For x = 1 To x

        For Each RangeArea In Columns(x).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas

            With RangeArea.Offset.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
                .Value = Application.Sum(RangeArea)
                .Font.Bold = 1
            End With

        Next RangeArea

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Davesexcel, that was really helpful. Thank you very much. But could you help with the one to calculate columns only? Like which bits do I edit such that it is able to be used for columns. Also, as I am importing multiple tables with a blank line btw each table, the sum column formula only calculates the grand total, but i dont need that. i need the subtotal of each little table to do my work. is there are a formula for that? the     =SUM(R[-" & lstRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C) formula seems to ignore blank spaces and continues calculating but i dont need that. Please advice. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Try the added code

Comment: hi @Davesexcel, the code you gave doesnt work too well... im quite clumsy so i dont think it will fit the 500+characters so ive edited my original post. I appreciate your help Dave.